# I got this error after upgrading neovim to version 0.7.2-2

Tags: lua, bytecode, neovim, incompatibility

I try to update neovim, to the latest version,It installed correctly, but when trying to view the version (nvim -v)  give me this error:

```
vim/_init_packages.lua: cannot load incompatible bytecode
stack traceback:
    [C]: at 0x56425eba1870
    [C]: at 0x7f85d7ffb3e0
E970: Failed to initialize builtin lua modules
```

I tried to uninstall it and re-install, but doesn't work.
also I tried to install it from the repository 'https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/' but it doesn't let me use the command 'nvim' to open it from the terminal

PS: my os is manjaro linux.

Comment: Could you please share your config? Are you still getting this error?